# How to set SAS program macro variables through a python script

Tags: python, parameters, automation, sas

I have multiple SAS program files, each of which has various macro variables which need to be set dynamically through an excel file. I was wondering if I can pass the values from the excel file to the SAS program through a python script (or shell script). I wish to automate the process of setting parameter for each SAS program manually.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why not just import the excel files in SAS?

Comment: I am trying to automate the execution of all sas programs by setting their parameters through the common excel file.I am reading the excel file and based on the program name I want to set parameters for that particular code file in SAS. If I had to import excel in SAS it does not automate anything for me. @superfluous

Comment: @codemob Well, you could read it into SAS then set the parameters inside of the SAS job?

Comment: Anyway, are you asking a Python question (how do I run [arbitrary program] with [arbitrary parameters] given an excel file), or are you asking a SAS question (how do I run SAS in batch and pass parameters to it)?

Comment: I am asking a python question but it involves both. I have more than 100 SAS code files. Each of them use a different set of macro variables. I have an excel sheet which is used in setting the new values for these program variables. I was hoping to write a Python program which will read in this excel file with the name of the code file and its respective variable values and pass these values to the SAS program which inturn will run to give me the output. I am not sure how to pass variable values from Python to SAS. @Joe- I hope this explains?

Comment: Do you know how to run SAS in batch and pass parameters to it?

Comment: Havent processed SAS using a bash script yet. But is that the only way to go about it. I went for python because that is what I am comfortable with.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get any useful help if you can't answer the question I've posed twice now.  I suspect that's what you need to look into first (how to run SAS in batch mode, not `bash`, but `batch` - meaning running unattended in a noninteractive mode - and pass parameters to it).  If that's the question you have, look at the questions on SO first, then if you still are unsure ask that question.  I suspect that once you know the answer to that, the rest you already know, given your answers here.

Comment: You could have written a SAS program to do this as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a string to SAS using the `-sysparm` command line option, and this string will be available in SAS as the `&sysparm` automatic variable.

E.g. (from the command line:)

```
sas myprogram.sas -sysparm myparam
```

If you need to parse the string inside SAS, the `%scan()` macro function will probably be useful.

Answer (score 1):

So I did figure out how I can solve this:

```
        subprocess.call(['C:\\Program Files\\SASHome\\SASFoundation\\9.4\\sas.exe', '-config', config_path, '-autoexec', autoexec_path,'-sasinitialfolder',sasinitialfolder,'-sysin', sas_script_path,'-log',ori_log])
```

I made a subprocess call from python to run it in Bash and I am sending different parameters to this call with respect to the SAS program I am calling. The parameters which I pass from the subprocess call are captured in the SAS program through a %sysget command.Thank you.